# Locate the item that triggered the event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I need to intercept all the events triggered on a page and to stop them;
then I would like to send an XML message to a servlet that will return multiple clients.
Once the message is received, the event is run normally.

So I have two problems: intercept and stop all the events and then trigger the event delayed.

To listen for a click on any element on the page I thought I would add a `click` listener on `$(document)` which composes the correct XML message: but in this way i intercept the event on top level of bubbling!

1. If I write here a `preventDefault`/`stopPropagation` method, it is executed after the execution of event? How can I stop the event?
2. The `event.target` method returns the document element or the element that triggers the event initially?

Then,
If I compose the XML message using the target and the type of the event, when a client receive the message and triggers it programmatically, this can unleash a loop?

UPDATE:
the answer to the second question is given by http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html
where it is written:

> Even if an event is captured or bubbles up, the target / srcElement
> always remains the element Took place on the event.

Comment: You can answer #2 by testing it out. Concerning #1, yes, any event handler can react to it while it's bubbling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine which element triggered the event use this in the event callback:

```
console.log("LOG|Event> " + "target: " + event.target);
if(event.target.id) {
    console.log("LOG|Event> " + "target.id: " + event.target.id);
}
```

For cross browser please reference:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html

Comment: Thanks for reply, I knew that the method used is "target", my question was about who was the target obtained by capturing the event to higher levels of bubbling

Comment: Does this meet your criteria?